# Prove $ \forall x\in\mathbb{R} : |\sin{x}|<|x|$ geometrically

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, trigonometry, angle

For $x\in(-\frac{\pi}{2}, -\frac{\pi}{2})\setminus \{0\}$ we can say that since the area of sector of circle is greater than the triangle (ABC) area I have $2|\sin{x}|<2|x|$. But what's about x in the 2nd and 3rd quadrant?
Look at the figure to easily understand what I am saying (Note: I have drawn a circle with a radius $>1$ to have a larger circle, but I am referring to a unit circle)[image]

Comment: Do you mean for $x\in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$? That’s actually all you need to prove, because $\sin (x) \leq 1$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: For $x= 0$ it is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Area of the triangle is $$S_\triangle = \frac{1\cdot 1\cdot \sin x}{2}$$
Area of the sector is $$S_\text{sec} = \frac{1^2\cdot x}{2}$$
Since it is vivid from the picture below that $S_\text{sec} > S_\triangle$, we have
$$\sin x < x$$
As has already been noted in the comment, you just need to verify only for $x \in [-1, 1] \subset (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. The above argument can easily be extended to $\forall x \in [-1, 1]$ (**note:** equality occurs when $x=0$).

---

$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad~$[image]

Comment: But I would like to show it $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ not only in [-1,1]. How I can do this?

Comment: @gui if you can show it for $[-1,1]$, the other case is trivial. Assume $x \in \mathbb R \setminus [-1,1]$ then we have $|x| > 1$ which means that $|x| > 1 \ge |\sin x|$

Comment: Right..thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: The inequality is trivial when $\lvert x\rvert>1$. (It is also not true when $x=0$.)

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:** Arclength (with units of distance) is the product of the radius $1$ and the angle $x$. Show how this arclength is longer than the altitude by showing how on a Euclidean plane, a line segment is the shortest path between two points.